# Pandas: is there a difference of speed between the deprecated df.sum(level=...) and df.groupby(level=...).sum()?

Tags: pandas, vectorization

I'm using pandas and noticed a HUGE difference in performance between these two statements:

```
df.sum(level=['My', 'Index', 'Levels']) # uses numpy sum which is vectorized
```

and

```
df.groupby(level=['My', 'Index', 'Levels']).sum() # Slow...
```

First example is using the [numpy.sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), which is vectorized, as stated in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

Unfortunably, using `sum(level=...)` is deprecated in the API and produces an ugly warning:

> FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series
> aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
> Use groupby instead. df.sum(level=1) should use
> df.groupby(level=1).sum()

I don't want to use the non vectorized version and have a poor processing performance. How can I use `numpy.sum` along with `groupby` ?

Edit: following the comments, here is a basic test I have done: Pandas 1.4.4 , 10k random lines, 10 levels (index)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
print('pandas:', pd.__version__)

nb_lines = int(1e4)
nb_levels = 10
# sequences of random integers [0, 9] x 10k
ix = np.random.randint(0, nb_levels-1, size=(nb_lines, nb_levels))

cols = [chr(65+i) for i in range(nb_levels)] # A, B, C, ...
df = pd.DataFrame(ix, columns=cols)
df = df.set_index(cols)
df['VALUE'] = np.random.rand(nb_lines) # random values to aggregate

print('with groupby:')
%timeit -n 300 df.groupby(level=cols).sum()
print('without groupby:')
%timeit -n 300 df.sum(level=cols)
```

And the result is:

```
pandas: 1.4.4
with groupby:
5.51 ms ± 1.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 500 loops each)
without groupby:
<magic-timeit>:1: FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use groupby instead. df.sum(level=1) should use df.groupby(level=1).sum().
4.93 ms ± 40.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 500 loops each)
```

This is just an example, but the result is always faster without `groupby`. Changing parameters (levels, step size for the columns to group on, etc) does not change the result.
In the end, for a big data set, you can see the difference between the two methods (numpy.sum vs other).

[@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway), you results indicate a similar performance, however if you increase the number of levels, you should see results worsening with the groupby version -at least that's the results on my computer. See edited code so you can change the number of levels (example with 10 levels and 100k lines):

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase as UP

np.random.seed(0)
N = 100_000
nb_levels = 10
cols = [chr(65+i) for i in range(nb_levels)]

d = {cols[i]: np.random.choice(list(UP), size=N) for i in range(nb_levels)}
d.update({'num': np.random.random(size=N)})
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(cols)

print(pd.__version__)

print('with groupby:')
%timeit -n 300 df.groupby(level=cols).sum()
print('without groupby:')
%timeit -n 300 df.sum(level=cols)
```

... and the result:

```
1.4.4
with groupby:
50.8 ms ± 536 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 300 loops each)
without groupby:
<magic-timeit>:1: FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use groupby instead. df.sum(level=1) should use df.groupby(level=1).sum().
42 ms ± 506 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 300 loops each)
```

Thanks

Comment: slow in what sense? under the hood the sum with level does a groupby

Comment: @sammywemmy sum with level uses numpy.sum which is vectorized, whereas the explicit groupby with sum does not

Comment: that is incorrect. groupby's sum is vectorised. Have a look at the docs and even the underlying code ... it is open source so you can verify that easily

Comment: I suggest you add a sample dataset to your question, see here how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424537/463796 - then an objective measurement can be taken.

Comment: What huge performance difference? Tested with 1m rows. Avg. 306ms with `sum(level=...)` and 303ms with `groupby(...).sum()`. I'd call them equal

Comment: @w-m I have added I sample test Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be true, both approaches have a similar speed.

Setup (3 levels, 26 groups each, ~18k combinations of groups, 1M rows):

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase as UP

np.random.seed(0)
N = 1_000_000

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice(list(UP), size=N),
                   'B': np.random.choice(list(UP), size=N),
                   'C': np.random.choice(list(UP), size=N),
                   'num': np.random.random(size=N),}
                  ).set_index(cols)
```

Test:

```
pd.__version__
1.4.4

%%timeit # 3 times
df.sum(level=cols)
316 ms ± 85.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
287 ms ± 21.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
297 ms ± 54.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%%timeit # 3 times
df.groupby(level=cols).sum()
284 ms ± 41.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
286 ms ± 18.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
311 ms ± 31.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

##### udpated example from OP

```
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase as UP
np.random.seed(0)
N = 1_000_000
nb_cols = 10 
cols = [chr(65+i) for i in range(nb_cols)] 
d = {cols[i]: np.random.choice(list(UP), size=N) for i in range(nb_cols)}
d.update({'num': np.random.random(size=N)})
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(cols)

print(pd.__version__)
1.5.0


%%timeit
df.sum(level=cols)
3.36 s ± 478 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df.groupby(level=cols).sum()
2.94 s ± 444 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Actually your test has only three levels, when you increase them the performance worsen and matches my results. Numpy.sum outperforms the groupby. See code below.

Comment: Can you edit your question instead?

Comment: @Carmellose still get similar results (or `df.sum` slower), not sure if this is what owed me a downvote, I'm just trying to reproduce your potential issue…

Comment: what about version 1.4.4? Are the results the same than with 1.5.0?

Comment: @Carmellose maybe a bit slower for groupby. Not sure if this is significant. There could also have been improvements between the two versions. Why don't you try your code on 1.5.0?

Comment: Thanks. Not using 1.5.0 because my stack is constrained by a production environment and don't have access to it :(